# Merge-Sort Issues

Tags: java, mergesort

So a little background:

Our teacher basically sat down and made a basic implementation of SQL in Java, you could say. He told us to try and make an implementation of a Merge-Algorithm in this system that he made.

I am trying to do a Merge-Sort (Top-Down Implementation) but I have a few issues.

The Merge-Sort is supposed to take two Tables (simulated from the Database implementation he made) and arrange them so that they show from lowest to highest in ascending order (1-8).

The code lets me use a DbIterator which our teacher wrote to iterate over a Table and its contents. So we have two tables which have the following data:

```
[hello1, 5]
[hello2, 6]
[hello3, 7]
[hello4, 8]
```

And the other table:

```
[goodbye4, 4]
[goodbye2, 2]
[goodbye3, 3]
[goodbye1, 1]
```

After a merge-sort it's supposed to print out this:

```
[goodbye1, 1]
[goodbye2, 2]
[goodbye3, 3]
[goodbye4, 4]
[hello1, 5]
[hello2, 6]
[hello3, 7]
[hello4, 8]
```

But this is what it prints out:

```
null
[hello1, 5]
[hello2, 6]
[hello3, 7]
```

I am sort of puzzled at this and have tried to debug to figure out what goes wrong, but I might have tried so much that I become blind to the actual issue. So here is the code (the sort happens on the last three methods):

```
public String[] MergeSort(String table1, String table2) {
    DbIterator scannerA = getTableScanner(table1);
    DbIterator scannerB = getTableScanner(table2);
    HashMap<Integer, String> records = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = 0;
    scannerA.open();
    while(scannerA.hasNext()) {
        Record r = scannerA.next();
        StringField sF = (StringField) r.getField(0);
        IntegerField iF = (IntegerField) r.getField(1);
        records.put(iF.hashCode(), sF.toString());
        A.add(iF.hashCode());
        n++;
    }
    scannerA.close();

    scannerB.open();
    while(scannerB.hasNext()) {
        Record r = scannerB.next();
        StringField sF = (StringField) r.getField(0);
        IntegerField iF = (IntegerField) r.getField(1);
        records.put(iF.hashCode(), sF.toString());
        B.add(iF.hashCode());
        n++;
    }
    scannerB.close();

    int[] mergeResult;
    int[] aA = convertIntegers(A);
    int[] bB = convertIntegers(B);
    mergeResult = TopDownSplitMerge(aA, 0, n, bB);
    String[] results = new String[mergeResult.length];
    for(int v = 0; v < mergeResult.length; v++) {
        if(records.containsKey(v)) {
            results[v] = "[" + records.get(v) + ", " + v +"]";
        }
    }

    return results;
}

private int[] CopyArray(int[] B, int iBegin, int iEnd, int[] A) {
    for(int k = iBegin; k < iEnd; k++)
        A[k] = B[k];
    return A;
}

private int[] TopDownSplitMerge(int[]A,int iBegin, int iEnd, int[]B) {
    if(iEnd - iBegin < 2) {
        return null;
    }
    int iMiddle = (iEnd + iBegin) / 2;
    TopDownSplitMerge(A, iBegin, iMiddle, B);
    TopDownSplitMerge(A, iMiddle, iEnd, B);
    TopDownMerge(A, iBegin, iMiddle, iEnd, B);
    int[] tmp = CopyArray(B, iBegin, iEnd, A);
    return tmp;
}

public void TopDownMerge(int[] A, int iBegin, int iMiddle, int iEnd, int[] B) {
    int i0 = iBegin;
    int i1 = iMiddle;

    for(int j = iBegin; j < iEnd; j++) {
        if(i0 < iMiddle && (i1 >= iEnd || A[i0] <= A[i1])) {
            B[j] = A[i0++];
        } else {
            B[j] = A[i1++];
        }
    }
}
```

First of all, this is not my personal algorithm but rather me trying to implement it from a wiki. The only part I cannot figure out, which might solve the whole issue all together, is what they call "iEnd". The value `n`. I can't figure out how to calculate that or what value to give. Might be the whole problem really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `TopDownMerge` – is merges items from two sorted parts of `A` array into corresponding part of `B`, then`CopyArray` copies merged data back to `A`. So `B` is just a temporary buffer for merging data, not the data source. You should not invoke `TopDownSplitMerge` with two arrays of input `aA` and `bB` but rather concatenate them into a single array and use that array as `A` parameter (and another array as `B` buffer).